# How to implement MPI in my C program to read file & remove space from it

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to C, After 4 days, I finally managed to make a program that read a file and remove space from it. I need to also make it parallel using MPI in any way. I tried various solutions, but MPI does not seem straightforward, it is complex, can someone please help me a bit to move forward.

Here is my code. It first reads a text file, and then removes space and new line characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <mpi.h>

FILE* pInputFile;
int chr = 0;
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr;

    char c;
    char filename[] = "Lorem.txt";
    char* str, * strblank;
    int i = 0;


    errno_t err;

    if ((err = fopen_s(&pInputFile, filename, "r")) == 0)
    {
        /*count the number of characters in file for file initialization*/
        size_t pos = ftell(pInputFile);    // Current position
        fseek(pInputFile, 0, SEEK_END);    // Go to end
        size_t length = ftell(pInputFile); // read the position which is the size
        fseek(pInputFile, pos, SEEK_SET);  // restore original position


        //creating dynamic array of file size
        str = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        strblank = malloc(length * sizeof(char));


        while ((chr = getc(pInputFile)) != EOF)
        {

            str[i] = chr;
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;
        printf("%s", str);

        removespace(str, strblank);
        printf("%s", strblank);


        fclose(pInputFile);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file, error %d\n", err);
    }
    return 0;
}
int removespace(char aj[500], char mj[500])
{


    int i = 0, j = 0, len;

    len = strlen(aj);   // len stores the length of the input string

    while (aj[i] != '\0')    // till string doesn't terminate
    {
        if (aj[i] != ' ' && aj[i] != '\n')  // if the char is not a white space
        {
            /*
                incrementing index j only when
                the char is not space
            */
            mj[j++] = aj[i];
        }
        /*
            i is the index of the actual string and
            is incremented irrespective of the spaces
        */
        i++;
    }
    mj[j] = '\0';
    printf("\n\nThe string after removing all the spaces is: ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO, this is not a good problem to be parallelized with MPI

Comment: Processing text files with the MPI_File routines is not straightforward.   A better "new to MPI" project would be something that is "embarrassingly parallel" such as monte-carlo estimation of pi.